# Create API Endpoints in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-apiserver

I am new to Kubernetes, so the there might already be new solutions which I am missing here.

**Requirement**

How do I create and API endpoint in Kubernetes which I can use to spawn new deployments and services?

**Why do I require API Endpoint??**

The requirement is such that new service needs to be get spawned whenever there are information (say name of new service, port it should run on, what config and resources it uses, so on...) pis provided by already running service (say service A).

So, when these informations are fed to the endpoint, a service running behind that api endpoint will create a template based on obtainted infromation, and execute necessary commands to spawn the new services.

**If there is any better approach than this please suggest me as well.**

Comment: Do you want to create a new API endpoint (not served by standard kube-api server) or use the existing kubernetes API endpoints in order to create standard cluster objects like `Pods`, `Deployments` or `Services` based on the input information ? How do you interact with kubernetes API ? Have you considered using some standard library e.g. [kubernetes python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to interact with kubernetes API from your app ?

Comment: Hey @mario thank you for the suggestion.
It was my bad for not checking in on the kubernetes client. Finally I figured out what needs to be done.

Comment: if kubernetes client library meets your requirements, you may consider sharing it as an answer to your question and describe in a few words how it fits into your use case and how it solves your issue. Posting an answer and marking it as accepted will clearly suggest to other users that this issue has been solved and doesn't require further answers.

Comment: Hy @mario thank you I will do it. I am still trying thing out on my end so still keeping it open. Once my application based on your suggestion is completed, I will move ahead with the answer. But I do not knowhow to mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the solution was to using some standard library e.g. kubernetes python client to interact with kubernetes API from my application as suggested by @mario.

I will share further solution on how I wrote the api using python client and may be even using go ;)